# Does next js support back forward cache (https://web.dev/bfcache/)

Tags: next.js, swr, bfcache

I am trying to add b/f cache in nextjs website, when we run (Test back/forward cache) in chrome browser, its run successfully "Successfully served from back/forward cache.". but when we
redirect to other pages and going back it still loading complete page again and making api calls.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.